# Agregar repositorio privado de github a cpanel

Tags: github, cpanel

Tengo que subir una web a cPanel, la web se trabaja de forma colaborativa a través de un repositorio privado en GitHub y a la hora de intentar clonar el repositorio al servidor en cPanel. Manda el siguiente mensaje de error.

`Error: “/usr/local/cpanel/3rdparty/bin/git” informó el código de error “128” cuando finalizó: fatal: could not read Username for 'https://github.com': No such device or address.`

Por lo que pude leer me parece que el error es causado por ser un repositorio privado. ¿Hay forma de solucionar esto?

Comment: Ya que dices que es privado, ¿cómo estás autenticando la conexión de cPanel a github? Ya generaste las llaves SSH y ya la subiste a GitHub para que el cliente en cPanel se pueda autenticar?

Answer (score 0):

Es probable que el problema que no tengas seteados tus credenciales o no cuentes con los permisos adecuados para poder bajar el proyecto.

Answer (score 0):

Aunque es antiguo la solución a ese error es :

No utilizar https hay que cambiarlo por ssh

Git@github.com:nombreUsuario/nombre repositorio.git

Requisitos previos:

- Generar llaves ssh privada y pública ( puede ser en tu computadora )
- Importar y Autorizar las llaves en cpanel
- Agregar llaves ssh en github ( carpetas privadas settings - deploy Keys) Agregar la llave pública y permitir lectura y escritura)

Luego ir a clonar.